# How to make jQuery/Javascript work in PHP statement?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I'm having some difficulties getting Javascript to execute in a PHP statement if it is possible at all. Below I have the code, if the field `'First'` is empty, then the background color of a certain div will be yellow. How can I get this to work properly if it is possible in the first place? Thanks in advance.

```
if (empty($_POST["First"])) {

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo '$("div").css({"background-color":"yellow"});';
    echo '</script>';

}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not doing this check in javascript instead of PHP?

Comment: No particular reason, I was just wondering if it is possible and if so, how to achieve it.

Comment: Consider adding a class to the div in PHP, and then having that class in CSS to set the background colour.

Comment: Also, something that it is going to really help you is to use like that `<?php 
if (empty($_POST["First"])) { ?>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   $("div").css({"background-color":"yellow"});
   </script>

   <?php
  } 
  
  ?>`

Comment: What is the difficulty? It looks correct assuming you have loaded jQuery before the statement. Any console errors?

Comment: @AntonisTsimouros Yes, I should probably do that instead.

Comment: Also, be careful for that last bracket. Never have it like that `<?php}?>`, there must be a space between `<?php` and `code code code` . Also don't forget to breath..jk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this code. hope it will help you

```
<div>Content Div</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
 //$_POST["First"] = ''; if you want to check this code execute then remove comment then run this code
 if (empty($_POST["First"])) {
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo '$("div").css("background-color","yellow");';
echo '</script>';
}
?>
```

you can also use this code

```
<div>Content Div</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
//$_POST["First"] = ''; this is for test case if you want to check then remove comment then run this code
 if (empty($_POST["First"])) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("div").css("background-color","yellow");
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

in this code php tag and javascript tag use separate

Answer (score 0):

You should try putting script tags inside php tags, like this:

```
<?php 
    if (empty($_POST["First"])) { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        '$("div").css({"background-color":"yellow"});';
        </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13254287/7808973